# Mapping Spring's health indicators to metrics

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer

I want map each spring's health indicator to prometheus metric. Similar to http://micrometer.io/docs/guide/healthAsGauge, but for each health indicator. I use spring boot 2 + micrometer + prometheus. Is there any elegant way to do this? Id

Comment: do you want a separate metric name for each health indicator? The example you mention does create a separate metric for each health indicator. It uses tags to distinguish each health indicator.

Answer (score 2):

A solution can be:

```
@Configuration
public class HealthMetricsConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MeterRegistryCustomizer prometheusHealthCheck(HealthEndpoint healthEndpoint) {
        return registry -> registry.gauge("health", healthEndpoint, HealthMetricsConfiguration::healthToCode);
    }

    public static int healthToCode(HealthEndpoint ep) {
        Status status = ep.health().getStatus();

        return status.equals(Status.UP) ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

you can bind all your Health metrics in the registry.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution. It creates for each HealthIndicater a metric with the health indicator's name as attribute value. A metric value 1 signals a healthy indivator, otherwise there is a problem.

```
    @Bean
public MeterRegistryCustomizer<MeterRegistry> healthRegistryCustomizer(HealthContributorRegistry healthRegistry) {
    return registry -> healthRegistry.stream().forEach(namedContributor -> registry.gauge("health", Tags.of("name", namedContributor.getName()), healthRegistry, health -> {
        var status = ((HealthIndicator) health.getContributor(namedContributor.getName())).getHealth(false).getStatus();
        return healthToCode(status);
    }));
}

public static int healthToCode(Status status) {
    return status.equals(Status.UP) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a cleanup of the previous solutions.

```
@Bean
MeterRegistryCustomizer<MeterRegistry> metricsHealthGauge(HealthEndpoint healthEndpoint) {
    log.info("Registering application_health metric gauge");
    return registry ->
        Gauge.builder("application_health", healthEndpoint, e -> e.health().getStatus().equals(Status.UP) ? 1 : 0).register(registry);
}
```